# Is it possible to stop Visual Studio Code from creating `.vscode` files?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on an operating system in a lecture and we decided to use Git in order to have a better overlook on our files and changes.
However, I came into trouble with Visual Studio Code, because it creates local `.vscode` files which I don't want to commit. Is there a way to stop Visual Studio Code from creating `.vscode` files or are they necessarily in order that Visual Studio works?

(I never pushed the `.vscode` files, that's why `.gitignore` won't work and I don't want to push unnecessarily files to the repository.)

---

### EDIT

With the help of the suggestions in the comment-section, I finally created a .gitignore file for VisualStudio Code with the help of [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/), pushed it to the repository and now everything is working perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Why is the creation of the .vscode files a problem? Have you tried pulling the repo in a new location and see if the absence of the .vscode files causes issues?

Comment: Ask git to ignore the .vscode file or folder, just add a line of `.vscode` to the `.gitignore` file and you should be fine, assuming you've not already added and thus tracked that file.

Comment: And that last paragraph indicates that you don't fully understand how .gitignore works, make sure you read up on what it does.

Comment: @TriskalJM Visual Studio Code will create new .vscode files every time I open a file, that's why it doesn't make a difference if I pull the repo in a new location.

Comment: @Doesbaddel using `.gitignore` is exactly what this situation is for - files you NEVER want added to the source control

Comment: What @Vlad274 said: use .gitignore

Comment: I edited my question, thank you for helping me out. Btw, you can post a real answer in order that I can accept it as the solution to my question.

Comment: I don't think VSCode does this actually, it might be one of the extensions you have installed?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the git extension?